# RegistryItem IndicatorItems in OpenIOC - what levels are required

Tags: ioc

I have seen people specify

`RegistryItem/KeyPath, RegistryItem/ValueName, RegistryItem/Value`

to fully specify the value of a registry entry, and others just use

`RegistryItem/Path, RegistryItem/Text`

How do I know the proper way of creating this XML element, and if I'm interpreting it, how do I know what to expect?

---

Using the XML from

http://openioc.org/terms/Current.iocterms

(with `display-type="string" term-source="application/vnd.mandiant.mir"` removed)

`<iocterm data-type="xs:string" text="RegistryItem/KeyPath" title="Registry Key Path" />
<iocterm data-type="xs:string" text="RegistryItem/Value" title="Registry Value" />
<iocterm data-type="xs:string" text="RegistryItem/ValueName" title="Registry Value Name" />`

versus

`<iocterm data-type="xs:string" text="RegistryItem/Path" title="Registry Path" />
<iocterm data-type="xs:string" text="RegistryItem/Type" title="Registry Type" />`

As an example, this IOC uses `RegistryItem/Path` and `RegistryItem/Text`

http://openioc.org/iocs/ea3cab0c-72ad-40cc-abbf-90846fa4afec.ioc

where as this one uses `RegistryItem/Path` and `RegistryItem/ValueName`

http://openioc.org/iocs/72669174-dd77-4a4e-82ed-99a96784f36e.ioc